# Using the generic type 'SignInManager<TUser, TKey>' requires 2 type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to implement the Login method using Async and Await methods:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Login(Models.Login login, string returnUrl)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(login);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync<UserLoginInfo,string>(login.EmailID, login.Password);
        switch(result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToAction("Account", "Privacy");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendUrl", new { ReturnUrl=returnUrl });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(login);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }

   // return View();
}
```

Getting this error:

> Error CS0305   Using the generic type 'SignInManager' requires 2 type arguments

Comment: Looks like `SignInManager` is a type, not an instance of your type.

Comment: Just read this again <UserLoginInfo,string>(login.EmailID, login.Password)

Comment: @Matej Stagi <UserLoginInfo,string>(login.EmailID, login.Password) this line is suggested by one of the sites.

Comment: @DavidG i didn't understand what you told

Comment: @DavidG is saying that you need to create an instance (e.g. `var signInMgr = new SignInManager()`) and use that instance (e.g. `await signInMgr.PasswordSignInAsync()`).  At present you are trying to call a method against the `type`, hence your error message.